# How to do Search Engine Optimization in SharePoint Internet Site?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I am creating a **SharePoint 2010** web site and want to launch it as an Internet website.
Now I want to do **SEO** (Search Engine Optimization) of my SharePoint Site.

Does anybody know how to do **SEO** (Search Engine Optimization) in SharePoint 2010 Internet website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is NO Out-of-box feature, there are couple ways to do it

**Mandatory Step** :

-> Create a custom Page Content Type with desired meta fields (author, keywords , description...etc)
-> Make sure to use the the content type created for all the pages

**Option 1 (Delegate)** :

-> Create a delegate control to read these fields and add to the HEAD tag. ( use the **PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead** )

**OR**

**Option 2 (add Fields)** :

pages fields can also be added, follow this article [Custom SEO](http://evgeniafisher.blogspot.com/2011/11/seo-for-sharepoint-2010.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use sub sites properly build your urls to different pages. You most likely will not want to add all of your site pages into one pages library, rather use sub pages to help build good, SEO frienly url's to each page.